# Xamarin TableViewCell select one

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, radio-group, xamarin-studio

I am trying to make table view cell as follows using Xamarin Studio.

[image]

public enum Category
{
    Travel,
    Lodging,
    Books
}

I am using Monotouch.Dialog, but cannot find any element.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is the `RadioElement` of MonoTouch.Dialog. You can see an example in section 3.1 in the [MonoTouch.Dialog introduction](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog).

From the example in the doc:

```
var root = new RootElement ("Meals") {
    new Section ("Dinner"){
        new RootElement ("Dessert", new RadioGroup ("dessert", 2)) {
            new Section () {
                new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "dessert"),
                new RadioElement ("Milkshake", "dessert"),
                new RadioElement ("Chocolate Cake", "dessert")
            }
        }
     }
}
```

With this example, you'll have a dialog with one root element called `Meals`. When tapping this item, you will be presented a new dialog where you can select one of the RadioElements. You create a `RadioGroup` for the elements that belong together, and the `RootElement` from which you launch the `RadioGroup` will show the currently selected value. There's more information about this in section 4.8. of the provided link as well.

Comment: RadioElement is for checking/unchecking the item, and I saw the script style rough example, but I couldn't find detail implementation, so I post this question.

Comment: Yes, but `RadioElement` is the closest you'll get with out of the box MonoTouch.Dialog elements.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the example from the documentation.